# Ubuntu 17.10 does not Boot on Dell XPS 15

Tags: boot, dell, encryption, 17.10, xps

I picked up a new Dell XPS 15 (9560) yesterday at a local store so of course I wiped Windows with a new Ubuntu 17.10 installation.

Picked some fairly standard options during install:

- Overwrite entire disk with Ubuntu.
- Encrypt Entire disk (which enforces the use of LVM).
- Pull latest updates during installation.

I had to use **nomodeset** to get the above to boot at all.

After a successful installation and entering my LUKS passphrase it freezes.

Dropping the **quiet** & **splash** options shows the following error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYVAq.jpg

I tried setting **nomodeset** again as a boot option as this is given as a common fix but all I got was a blank Ubuntu Purple screen where it stays forever. I don't even get prompted for my LUKS passphrase now.

Dropping to a recovery shell is useless as I cannot seem to connect to the network. Though really I feel like I'm missing something as I shouldn't be jumping through this many hoops just to get my system through it's first boot.